# What is the purpose of the SD card on an Asus ZenPad

Tags: sd-card

I had this issue on the Dell Venue but was never resolved. On an ASUS ZenPad, what is the purpose of the SD card if it can't be accessed? So how does one play movies from the SD card?

Answer (score 0):

4.4 had a change that made all but one folder per app on the sdcard read only, but you could disable that... you should be using 7.1 anyway... why can't you access it? Did you format it as internal storage? If so you are using it, just transparently.

Is this the correct model? https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/P024_Info

Answer (score 0):

Check that it is not formatted for a pc, which usually uses ntfs, whereas android can only read fat32 (also readable by windows, but has 4gb max file size :( and ext4. I also saw people in forums talking about the asus zenpad not supporting exfat, so make sure it's not formatted as that either. To reformat using windows: https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/index.html
hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks very much for that, really. However, when I used that formatter it showed upon completion that it was still exfat. The only options available when formatting were quick or full and had nothing to do with chosing fat32 or anything else. Know of another formatter maybe?

Comment: Maybe try http://tokiwa.qee.jp/EN/Fat32Formatter/

Comment: Didn't make it easy to use and I never could get it to work, too much commercial stuff going on there and adding add ons that I didn't want. I tried using pre formatted cards, anything 32GB or smaller were formatted FAT32, which is good, but now I have issues with them not copying right somehow. They copy, they show filed and of course they are listed as each chapter of the movie instead of the whole movie but I could live with that if they didn't playback stills instead of action.